# How to work around cross-frame cross-origin scripting protection in an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I use currently the `--disable-web-security` and the `--disable-site-isolation-trials` flags to do cross-frame cross-origin scripting in Chrome. As far as I know Chrome developers will remove that feature soon and there is no guarantee I can use anything after that. I am looking for alternatives and I am curious if I can use Chrome or Firefox extensions to completely override a page on the target origin? E.g. the target is `https://example.com` and I want to override `https://example.com/script.runner/` to load my content from a Karma server maybe through the extension somehow. That way I could do cross-frame same-origin scripting, which is allowed by the browser. Is this possible?

Note:

If you want to write about postMessage in your answer, then rather close this tab.

Comment: Extensions can redirect request URLs with chrome.webRequest API to another URL, like for example a data:// URI with a literal text of the replacement script.

Comment: Another approach would be Puppetteer or a similar tool that emits remote debugging protocol commands to intercept and redirect the URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Data URI is on a different origin. Redirection does not work here. I need to override a complete page somehow.

Comment: @wOxxOm Are you talking about normal HTTP redirection? If so, I already wrote that it does not work. Redirecting to a different origin means cross frame cross origin scripting which won't be allowed after they end supporting these flags. All I could do is injecting my page to the target origin and run my scripts there. Injecting a script tag to the head is not good enough for me, because I cannot prevent the scripts of the target to run. That's because I cannot touch DOM and remove them before DOMContentLoaded and they run before that event is fired.

Comment: I see. Well, since Chrome extensions don't have a dedicated API to replace the response body, only Firefox WebExtensions have it, your extension would have to emit Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol commands to replace the response body via chrome.debugger extension API.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I'll check it. For me even Firefox is enough, it does not have to be Chrome.